# How to proramatically publish web application as Web App to Azure using Azure Resource Manager REST API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, publish

I would like to develop my custom application wherein I can fill all required details for authentication on Azure and then select a web application package to publish on Azure as Web Application under App Services (not as cloud service).

Scenario:

1. A win form application to gather required details. For e.g. Publish settings, certificate, App Service Selection, any other selection, etc.
2. I will have my web application in zip format.
3. When submit, application should publish my web application on customer's Azure's Web Application under App Service.

Also, is it possible to copy some files under ProgramData after publish completes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do all that:

- using [Kudu](https://github.com/cloudera/kudu) interface to your App Service. (Check the [Zip interface](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip))
- using [PowerShell cmdlets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell) to your Azure accounts(s).

If you app is on a straight VM, you can use any combination of scripting tool (bash, chef, puppet, capistrano, etc.) to access the vm and do whatever you want.

This works great for all kind of app technologies.